# Understanding of the word "opinionated"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I'm a little confused about the word *opinionated*. From a dictionary, it means:

> someone who is opinionated has very strong opinions that they refuse to change even when they are clearly unreasonable

So it seems *opinionated* is a bad thing. But I saw many products claim that they are *an opinionated something*. Like [this tool](https://github.com/prettier/prettier), which *is an opinionated code formatter*. What does it mean in this context? Why they use this kind of disapproving word in there product description?

Comment: People often take a negative word and apply it to themselves as a way of blunting future criticism, or as humor. That's what the tool is doing. People will complain about its strictness, so to head that off, they just embraced it.